# catch always get called

Tags: php, kohana, kostache

I'm having problem saving data to the database since catch exception is always being called. try always get ignored. I don't really know what's happening. I've been working for this for hours and I can't get it to work. I'm using kohana 3.3 and kostache.

So here's the controller.

**Controller**

*APPATH/classes/controller/album.php*

```
public function action_create()
    {
                $view = Kostache_Layout::factory();
                $layout = new View_Pages_Album_List();
                $album = ORM::factory('Album_Information');
                $album_name = $this->request->post('inputAlbum');           
                $artist = $this->request->post('inputArtist');  
                $album->Album_Name = $album_name;
                $album->Artist = $artist;

                try
                {
                    $album->save();
                    HTTP::redirect('album');
                }
                catch(ORM_Validation_Exception $e)
                {
                    $layout->errors = $e->errors('models');
                }
            }   

        $this->response->body($view->render($layout));
    }
```

**Templates**

*APPATH/templates/pages/album/list.mustache*

```
<h3>Add A New Album</h3>
<form action="album/create" method="post">

<label for="inputAlbum">Album Name:</label>
<input id="inputAlbum" type="text" name="inputAlbum" /><br />
<label for"inputAlbum" class="error">{{#errors}}{{inputAlbum}}{{/errors}}</label>

<label for="inputArtist">Album Artist:</label>
<input id="inputArtist" type="text" name="inputArtist" /><br />
<label for="inputArtist" class="error">{{#errors}}{{inputArtist}}{{/errors}}</label>

<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" />
</form>
```

**Model Rules**

*APPATH/classes/model/album/information.php*

```
class Model_Album_Information extends ORM
{
    protected $_primary_key = 'ID';
    protected $_table_name = 'album_information';

    public function rules()
    {
        return array(
                'inputAlbum' => array(
                    array('not_empty'),
                    ),
                'inputArtist' => array(
                    array('not_empty'),
                    ),
        );
    }
```

**Messages**

APPATH/messages/models/album.php

```
return array(
        'inputAlbum' => array(
            'not_empty' =>  ':You must provide Album Name',     
            ),
        'inputArtist' => array(
            'not_empty' => ':You must provide Album Artist',
        ),
    );
```

The errors are showing when there's no input on the input field when i hit on the submit button, no problem with that, but even there's an input the errors are still being shown. So catch is always being called. When i remove try and catch I can easily save data to the database but there's no validation.

Thank you and more power.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You expect the ORM class to magically know the value of `$album->Album_Name` came from a HTTP form input named `inputAlbum`. It won't.

Create rules for the `Album_Name` and `Artist` properties of the ORM object itself. Not the possible input method.

The Controller knows what data to pass to models. The Model is only concerned with the data it received. Not where it came from.

Comment: Well that fix it. I did what you said and got it working. Thanks for the help man.